# will_paginate with Ransack causes parameters error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, ransack

I am using the will_paginate gem and ransack gem in a rails 5.2 app. When I search or sort I get the following error:

`unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash`

The highlighted line of code is this:

`tag :li, link(page, page, :rel => rel_value(page)), class: classes`

The good people at Ransack have their own will_paginate fork that solves the issue. However, that fork doesn't include the very nice `page_entries_info`

using `page_entries_info` give an error about an array.

Has anyone solved these issues with will_paginate and Rails 5.2?

Has anyone created a fork on github of will_paginate that resolves the issue?

I would be glad to contribute. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be fixed in the latest version of the gem (3.17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an initialize where you overwrite the symbolized_update method.

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer.class_eval do
  def symbolized_update(target, other, blacklist = nil)
    other.each_pair do |key, value|
      key = key.to_sym
      existing = target[key]
      next if blacklist && blacklist.include?(key)

      if value.respond_to?(:each_pair) and (existing.is_a?(Hash) or existing.nil?)
        symbolized_update(existing || (target[key] = {}), value)
      else
        if value.instance_variable_defined?(:@parameters)
          value = value.instance_variable_get(:@parameters)
        end
        target[key] = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```